# Is there a code style or design for cross-platform without #ifdef preprocessing (C++17)?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform

I am currently editing Windows Cpp codes for Linux.

But, the way I know

`example 1`

```cpp
template <typename T>
static off_t SetFilePointerU(T handle, unsigned int fileOffset, const int flag)
{
#ifdef _WIN32

    return ::SetFilePointer(static_cast<void*>(handle), fileOffset, NULL, flag);

#elif __linux__
    
    return lseek(handle, fileOffset, flag);

#endif
}
template <typename T>
static unsigned long ReadFileU(T handle, void* readBuffer, const int readSize = READ_BUFFER_SIZE)
{
#ifdef _WIN32

    DWORD outReadSize;

    if (!::ReadFile(static_cast<void*>(handle), readBuffer, readSize, &outReadSize, NULL))
    {
    
    }

    return outReadSize;

#elif __linux__

    return read(handle, readBuffer, readSize);

#endif
}
```

---

`example2`

```cpp
#ifdef __linux__
            std::wstring u16FilePath{ updateInfo.strFilePath.begin(), updateInfo.strFilePath.end() };
            std::wstring u16FileName{ updateInfo.strFileName.begin(), updateInfo.strFileName.end() };
            auto pathList = deSerializer.GetRealPaths(u16FilePath);
#elif _WIN32
            auto pathList = deSerializer.GetRealPaths(updateInfo.strFilePath);
#endif

            for (auto& path : pathList)
            {
#ifdef __linux__
                std::u16string u16toWstringPath{ path.begin(),path.end() };
                updateInfo.strFilePath = u16toWstringPath;
#elif _WIN32
                updateInfo.strFilePath = path;
#endif
                if (updateInfo.updateType == 0)
                {
#ifdef __linux__
                    path.append(u16FileName);
#elif _WIN32
                    path.append(updateInfo.strFileName);
#endif
                    std::transform(path.begin(), path.end(), path.begin(), tolower);
                    updateDatInfos.emplace(path, updateInfo);
                }
                else
                { 
#ifdef _WIN32
                    updateDatInfofilePath = updateInfo.strFilePath;
                    updateDatInfofilePath += L"\\";
                    updateDatInfofilePath += updateInfo.strFileName;
                    std::filesystem::remove(updateDatInfofilePath);
#elif __linux__
                    std::u16string u16UpdateDatInfofilePath{ updateInfo.strFilePath.begin(), updateInfo.strFilePath.end() };
                    u16UpdateDatInfofilePath += u"/";
                    u16UpdateDatInfofilePath += updateInfo.strFileName;
                    std::filesystem::remove(u16UpdateDatInfofilePath);
#endif
```

This is the same way as above.

I think that there is a lot of preprocessing in the code, and the readability may decrease in the future.
Are there other methods for cross-platform development?

Q)I am using `ifdef` in several places in my code.
But I don't want to use `#ifdef` in multiple places in multiple files.

Is there any other good way?

Comment: Why don't you use the standard C++ library, like its file streams?

Comment: You also have other problems, like in the `ReadFileU` function where on Linux you return the result of `read`. But `read` can return *negative* values (for errors) which might not be handled nicely when being converted into an unsigned integer.

Comment: You can't really avoid using `#ifdef` in multiplatform code all you can do is constrain them to the minimum of places by putting the cross platform stuff in a single place with a common interface (or just use a library that does this for you)

Comment: I'm using the c++ standard functions as much as possible.

However,
Many Windows functions are used in the existing `3rd part` library that you want to use.

Also, I use std::wstring a lot.
But I know that wchar_t size is different on linux than windows. So, we added new structures and variables such as std::u16string in the middle.
@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @AlanBirtles
Thank you for answer.
Maybe i think code refactoring work is essential.

Comment: If you use `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` on Windows, why can't you use it on other systems as well? That `sizeof(wchar_t)` might be different on different systems should not really matter.

Comment: As for how to solve your current portability problem in a nicer way, think *abstractions* and *classes*. Create an abstract base-class defining the interface you need. Then do two implementations: One for Windows and one for POSIX (which includes both Linux *and* macOS, plus other less used systems). Then the build-system could select which source-file to use, instead of you doing a lot of conditional compilation.

Comment: Why are you doing all these reinterpret_casts and const_casts to begin with? The `std::basic_string` family does its memory management for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
@AlanBirtles

thanks, everyone

i think Use `#ifdef` to place code within a single location and
it should be used by defining an interface that can be abstracted.

Comment: Another thing that helps with Unicode issues is to use utf-8 throughout your program, this just works on most macos and Linux systems then you just need to convert to `wchar_t` before calling Windows apis

Comment: @NathanPierson

Some of the comments were inaccurate and were deleted. thank you for the reply.

Comment: @AlanBirtles
Before using WINAPI
Do you mean using `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` in the main statement?

Comment: no, before each call to the windows api convert from utf-8 to wchar_t, see http://utf8everywhere.org/